# ¿Cómo redirigir al usuario a la pestaña de mi aplicación (cuando se encuentra activa otra) en el navegador, de forma automática?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Los dos ejemplos tienen un temporizador para ejecutar una función, quisiera saber como posicionar la pestaña al frente o que tenga foco como lo hace el `alert()` de `javascript`.

**Esta el primer ejemplo:** el cual tiene el `alert()` y hace el evento que quisiera hacer (OJO: sin el `alert()`).

```js
var temp = setTimeout(alertaJavascript, 5000);

function alertaJavascript() {
  alert('function alertaJavascript()');
}
```

**Esta el segundo ejemplo:** el cual tiene una función que se ejecuta pero no encuentro como hacer que la pestaña se venga al frente (que tenga el foco) como lo hace el `alert()`.

```js
var temp = setTimeout(alertaJavascript, 5000);

function alertaJavascript() {
  $( document ).focus();
  window.focus();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Actualización 1**: especificando el asunto.

Si la pestaña que contiene la "app" tiene una función como la que muestro (con temporizador) y el usuario se fue a otras pestañas, digamos "Google" y se coloco a indagar y buscar X cosas y se le olvido que tiene abierta la "app" en otra pestaña, esta al ejecutarse la función (por temporizador) coloque el foco, es decir, se le active esa pestaña.

Comment: ¿a qué te refieres con *foco*?

Comment: @Jorius Si la pestaña que contiene la "app" tiene una función como la que muestro (con temporizador) y el usuario se fue a otras pestañas, digamos "Google" y se coloco a indagar y buscar X cosas y se le olvido que tiene abierta la "app" en otra pestaña, esta al ejecutarse la función (por temporizador) coloque el foco, es decir, se le active esa pestaña.

Comment: Creo que podrías agregar dicho comentario al cuerpo de la pregunta, es mucho más específico y claro

Comment: @Jorius listo gracias por la sugerencia

Comment: @PabloContreras por seguridad javascript no puede mover el foco de una pestaña a otra sin autorización del usuario, para lograr eso, debes colocar un link (en la pagina donde este el usuario) que haga referencia al foco en la otra pestaña, de esta manera cuando el usuario haga click sobre el link este lo direccionara a la otra pestaña.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para realizar la acción solicitas el código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
window.onblur = function() {
 setTimeout(
   function(){ 
      window.focus();
   }, 3000);
}
```

Sin embargo, algunos navegadores, en sus versiones actuales, **NO** permiten la acción:

> window.focus();

Debido a problemas de **seguridad**.

Lo mas recomendable es que utilices el `alert()` de la siguiente forma:

```
window.onblur = function() {
 setTimeout(
   function(){ 
      alert('No abandones la página :(');
   }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: "dialog" es sinónimo de `alert()`, no quiero un ventana emergente, no quiero un modal, ni nada por el estilo, solo que la pestaña obtenga el foco.

Comment: No habia captado bien tu duda hasta que la editaste, editaré mi respuesta.

Comment: Gracias hermano.